# How can I create a custom editor for org.quartz.JobDetail?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to set up the CronTriggerFactoryBeanusing `Spring` and it has a property named **JobDetail** which I am trying to initialise.

```
  <bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="name" value="NTrigger"></property>
        <property name="group" value="Group Trigger"></property>
        <property name="jobDetail" value="Group Trigger"></property>
        <property name="cronExpression" value="${quartz.slaPollerCronExpression.timeInterval}"></property>
    </bean>
```

But I am getting an error as:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'cronTriggerForSLAPoller' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/quartz
-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value
of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.quartz.JobDetail' for property
'jobDetail'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.quartz.JobDetail
for property 'jobDetail': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.
```

I think it takes `String` as a default type.

I have a look at the `[propertyeditors][1]`. I think I will need to use `ClassEditor`. Am I thinking correct?

How can I remove this error? How can I create a custom editor for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to pass a reference instead of a string:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.quartz.JobDetail' for property 'jobDetail'
```

**CronTriggerFactoryBean**

```
/**
 * Set the JobDetail that this trigger should be associated with.
 */
public void setJobDetail(JobDetail jobDetail) {
    this.jobDetail = jobDetail;
}
```

See *[Chapter 23. Scheduling and Thread Pooling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html)*.

```
<bean id="exampleJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="exampleBusinessObject" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="doIt" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>


<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="exampleJob" />
    <!-- Runs every morning at 6 AM -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 * * ?" />
</bean>
```

Comment: they should not cause problems according to error description

Comment: Thanks.I think i am going the right way. But i have a doubt regarding **targetMethod** ? Here what should i write.Can i put it empty?

Comment: in this specific case with MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean, targetMethod is the method of object which spring will invoke on user specified bean(exampleBusinessObject)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a conversion pattern.

1. change  `<property name="jobDetail" value="Group Trigger"></property>` to  `<property name="jobDetail" ref="myconversion" />`
2. add a conversion pattern:

   ```
   <bean id="myconversion" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean"> 
   <property name="jobClass" value="com.nuance.ndm.ou.jobs.MserverCalllogTransformerJob" /> 
   <property name="jobDataAsMap"> 
     <map> 
       <entry key="groupTrigger" value="Group Trigger"" />            
     </map> 
   </property>
   ```